# Applying window function in one query without CTE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have been searched in the net and trying to create a query that contains a window function without a CTE but I couldn't get the result and I need some help 
this my query that I create with a CTE what I need is doing that in one query

```
;with cte(Gid, id, prod, orderdate, shipdate, ranking) as
(
    select 
        p1.Gid  Gid,
        p1.id id,
        p1.prod prod,
        p1.orderdate orderdate,
        p2.shipdate shipdate,
        rank() over (partition by p1.prod order by p1.id desc) ranking
    from 
        shpro p1 
    inner join 
        shpro p2 on p1.id = p2.id
    where 
        cast(p1.orderdate as DATE) > GETDATE() 
        and cast(p1.shipdate as DATE) < GETDATE() - 1
)
select * 
from cte 
where ranking = 1
```

Comment: What is the problem with using CTE? Why do you try to avoid CTE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>[Demo with some test data on how this works](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/516467)</kbd>

```
 select top (1) with ties
                p1.Gid  Gid,
                p1.id id,
                p1.prod prod,
                p1.orderdate orderdate,
                p2.shipdate shipdate       
          from shpro p1 inner join shpro p2
          on p1.id=p2.id
          where cast(p1.orderdate as DATE)>GETDATE() and cast(p1.shipdate as DATE)<GETDATE()-1
          order by
          Rank() over (partition by p1.prod order by p1.id desc)
```

This works like below..

1.order by arranges all the rows based on their rank
2.Top 1 with ties options fetches all the rows which are tied

**References:**
[T-SQL Querying (Developer Reference)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735685045)

**Below is some sample data to play with:**

```
  CREATE TABLE #TEST
    (
    Id INT,
    Name VARCHAR(10)
    )

    Insert Into #Test
    select 1,'A'
    Union All
    Select 1,'B'
    union all
    Select 1,'C'
    union all
    Select 2,'D'



select top 1 with ties id,name
from #test
order by row_number() over (partition by id order by id)
```

Answer (score 0):

CTE can be translated directly into subquery. Yours query should look similar to following:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    select 
        p1.Gid  Gid,
        p1.id id,
        p1.prod prod,
        p1.orderdate orderdate,
        p2.shipdate shipdate,
        rank() over (partition by p1.prod order by p1.id desc) ranking
    from 
        shpro p1 
    inner join 
        shpro p2 on p1.id = p2.id
    where 
        cast(p1.orderdate as DATE) > GETDATE() 
        and cast(p1.shipdate as DATE) < GETDATE() - 1
) CteAsSubquery
WHERE ranking = 1
```

Note alias CteAsSubquery is there (most common error).